# Cannot query a shard collection

Tags: mongodb

I created a shard with two replica sets. Each replica set have 3 `mongod` server and they work fine. Also, the `mongos` server seems to work. Here is it's status:

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "version" : 3,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
        "currentVersion" : 4,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("51c5be46dda9b0a5cd83ad64")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "s1/RemotePC_1:27017,RemotePC_1:27018,RemotePC_1:27019" }
        {  "_id" : "s2",  "host" : "s2/RemotePC_2:27017,RemotePC_2:27018,RemotePC_2:27019" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "student",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "s1" }
                student.grades
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        chunks:
                                s1      1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : s1 { "t" : 1, "i" : 0 }
```

But, when I run any command (insert, find, count, mongoimport) on the `student.grades` collection I get back this error:

```
mongos> db.grades.count()
Sat Jun 22 20:07:00.968 JavaScript execution failed: count failed: {
        "code" : 10429,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "exception: setShardVersion failed host: RemotePC_2:27017 { oldVersion: Timestamp 0|0, oldVersionEpoch: ObjectId
        ('000000000000000000000000'), errmsg: \"exception: all servers down/unreachable when querying: My-PC:57017,My-PC:57018,My-PC:57019\", code: 8002, ok: 0.0 }"
} at src/mongo/shell/query.js:L180
```

Why? Am I missing something?

Comment: what are "My-PC:57017,My-PC:57018,My-PC:57019" - are those by chance your config servers and are they perhaps unreachable?

Comment: Yes they are the config server and `My-PC` is the computer name of my pc. They are not unreachable. I can connect to them with `mongo` and in the the replica sets (RemotePC_2:27017...).

Comment: Ah, but you are local to "My-PC" - the mongod processes are NOT - so this means you cannot reach "My-PC" from "RemotePC" - at least not by the name that you gave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the members of the sharded cluster must be able to reach all the other members.

You are running `mongos` on your local machine, it can reach config servers which also run on your local machine, and it can reach the shards which are running on remote machines.

However, if the shards on remote machines cannot reach the config servers on your local machine they will *not* be able to operate properly within the cluster (and that is the error message that you are seeing).

The solution to this would be to restart `mongos` with the config server argument (`--configdb`) specified as hostnames which are routable (aka findable) from "remote-PC".  If you are running multiple `mongos` processes you will need to do that for all of them.

Comment: That was the problem. I installed the config and mongos servers on a computer where the replication server have access and it worked. Thank you.